# Mysterious error with jQuery validate and IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this little code:

```
alert(1);
$('input[name^="Quantity_"]').each(function () {
    alert(2);
    $(this).rules("add", { required: true, digits: true });
    alert(3);
});
alert(4);
```

In Chrome or Firefox, I see the alert 1, 2, 3 and 4, but with IE7, I see only the alert 1 & 2. Why the script failed on rules()?

**IE7 doesn't report an error in the page**

**EDIT 1:** The javascript failed on the line **$.data(element.form, 'validator').settings;** in jquery.validation.js script.
`Element.form` is not null, but `$.data(element.form, 'validator')` is undefined.

Thank you

Comment: Any way you could reproduce this on a site like http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you call `$("#YourForm").validate()` before using the `rules` method, as per the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules. In your case, I'd use that call before `alert(1)` or wherever you want to initialize your code.

Replace `#YourForm` with whatever selector you want.